# Mysql Parition Change from Key to Hash

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have got a table with Table with PARTITION BY KEY PARTITIONS 10;

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `table1 (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ref_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `target` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_time` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ref_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (`id`,`ref_id`) 
PARTITIONS 10 */
```

I want to Change this Partition to PARTITION BY HASH PARTITIONS 20; But not sure how to Change Key to Hash without losing data.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Neither partitioning method is useful; I recommend removing partitioning.  In doing so, you should probably remove `ref_id` from the `PRIMARY KEY`.

If you have reason to believe that partitioning helps in some way, I would like to pursue a debate.

It smells like `id` is a UUID or GUID.  If performance is the underlying question, I recommend you shrink the table by using BINARY(16); see [my uuid blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) for code for the conversion.  (Smaller --> faster)

**Edit** (Argument against Partitioning in this case)

A common misconception is that breaking a table into smaller chunks will improve performance.  Let's analyze, for example, a "point query" such as a `SELECT` where you specify one row via the `PRIMARY KEY`.

In an non-Partitioned table, it will drill down the BTree to find the row.  If the table has a few billion rows, the BTree will be about 5 levels deep.  That is, the lookup will need to hit about 5 index blocks to find the actual row.

In an equivalent Partitioned table, each partition is like a smaller table.  The point query will need to (1) locate the desired partition, then (2) drill down perhaps 4 levels in the BTree in that partition.  That's 1+4 operations -- probably about the same speed as the 5 in the non-Partitioned table.

Conclusion:  A point query does not benefit from Partitioning.

There are other types of queries that *might* benefit from partitioning.  For example if all the queries were aimed at on partition, that partition might be better cached.  But that "cannot" happen here.  The table is partitioned on a UUID (I assume), such is *very* random, so there is no way you would be looking at only one partition.

If you would care to share the common queries, I could further elaborate on which ones benefit (or not) from this (or other) form of Partitioning.

Comment: Hi Rick, Basically all my queries are based on id,ref_id so having ref_id in primary key is very much needed for lookup. Also this Table Host around 1.8billion records.thats why i think partition will help out to break the table in small chunks. Your comments on it.